# How i can check if a guid is empty in genexus 15?

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to check if a variable with data type `GUID` is empty, but all this way is going to `else`.

```
//Defined variable to empty `GUID`
&PRODUTOATRIBUTOVariacao.SetEmpty()

if &PRODUTOATRIBUTOVariacao.ToString().Trim() <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
     GDebug('Not empty')
else
     GDebug('Empty')
endif
```

This way i get the correct `Empty` log, but don't look the most appropriate way to check this.

I also tried:

```
if &PRODUTOATRIBUTOVariacao.ToString().Trim() <> GUID.Empty()
     GDebug('Not empty') else
     GDebug('Empty') endif
```

This way i get not empty

Answer (score 1):

Use `IsEmpty()` method:

```
&PRODUTOATRIBUTOVariacao.SetEmpty()
  ...
if &PRODUTOATRIBUTOVariacao.IsEmpty()
     GDebug('Empty')
else
     GDebug('Not empty')
endif
```